# Browser doesn't stop loading with jQuery $.get

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser, google-chrome

I use the following jQuery (1.4) code to test whether cookies are accepted:

```
$.get("http://localhost:8080/cookietester/cookietester", function(data) {
    if (data == "false")
        document.write("Activate cookies!");
    else if(data == "true")
        document.write("ok");
});
```

But the browser signals that it doesn't stop page loading. Google Chrome 5 doesn't execute the script properly and doesn't display anything.

Is something wrong with this code?

Comment: Check the debug console - you might be getting a non 200 response code. That callback only gets called upon success.

Comment: The URL leads to a redirect, but this is handled correctly by jQuery and "ok" is displayed. But it seems like the browser is still loading. The debug console doesn't report a bug and the status code after the redirect is 200.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.write) in that scenario (actually I avoid it whenever possible), instead use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add a message to the `<body>`, like this:

```
$.get("http://localhost:8080/cookietester/cookietester", function(data) {
  if (data == "false")
    $(document.body).append("Activate cookies!");
  else if(data == "true")
    $(document.body).append("ok");
});
```

Or, you could just alert it:

```
$.get("http://localhost:8080/cookietester/cookietester", function(data) {
  if (data == "false")
    alert("Activate cookies!");
  else if(data == "true")
    alert("ok");
});
```

Comment: That's it! This little changed solved all the problems and even Chrome just works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Don't call `document.write` there.

Calling `document.write` after the page is finished loading will reset the page, which is not what you want.

Instead, use jQuery to set the `text()` of an element.

Answer (score 0):

There might be another javascript code still running ?

Comment: No, there is only this script on the page.