# Page won't stop loading after fetching json from server

Tags: jquery

I am using this code to fetch some json from the server

```
$(function () 
  {
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'fetch.php',                          
      data: "",      
      dataType: 'json',                 
      success: function(data)          
      {
        jQuery.each(data, function() {
        document.write(this[0] + "<br/>" + this[1]);
         });
      }  
    });

  });
```

and i am having this on the server side

```
$rows = Array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  array_push($rows, $row);
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

When i try loading my html file with the json,the data is displayed but the page won't stop loading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem.I changed

```
document.write(this[0] + "<br/>" + this[1]);
```

to

```
$(document.body).append(this[0] + "<br/>" + this[1]);
```

but i can't claim to have done it entirely by myself.I got a tip from this post
[Browser doesn't stop loading with jQuery $.get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319177/browser-doesnt-stop-loading-with-jquery-get)

Answer (score 0):

Where is this code? Did you try to execute it in the ready event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // your ajax call here...
});
```

Comment: $(function ()  is a shorthand for $(document).ready(function()

Comment: `$(function () {}` is a shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){}`

Answer (score 0):

Open it with Chrome, open the Web Inspector (right click > inspect element) and go to the Network tab and refresh the website

you should see all the resources that your website is loading, including any AJAX requests
and you can clearly see what's still loading